# Linq to find match from three lits

Tags: c#, linq

I'm banging my head against the wall to try to figure something out.  I've broken down what I'm trying to figure out in the simplest explanation as I can below:

Let's say I have these two string arrays with the following data:

```
string[] firstName = new string[2];
string[] lastName = new string[2];

firstName[0] = "John";
firstName[1] = "Jane";

lastName[0] = "Doe";
lastName[1] = "Doe";
```

I then have a method that this arrays are passed into:

```
private void Matches(IEnumerable<string> firstNames, IEnumerable<string> lastNames)
{

}
```

I then have two variables:

```
string myFirstName = "John";
string myLastName = "Doe";
```

How can I use Linq in the Matches method to find a complete match on the names being passed in? (the header of the Matches method has to remain how it is, unfortunately) Based on that data, I could I find the matches? I'm going gray trying to figure this one out....lol

Comment: what should be the result? do you wanna know if `firstNames` contains `myFirstName` and `lastNames` contains `myLastName`? please clarify your question

Comment: Selman22 - I'm wanting to know if a match is found in the string arrays. For instance, I have the known value of John Doe (from myFirstName and myLastName). I need to be able to quickly find a match for that entire name in the string arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zip the two together and then just do a simple `Where`:

```
var myName = myFirstName + " " + myLastName;
firstNames.zip(lastNames, (first, last) => first + " " + last)
    .Where(fullName=>fullName == myName)
```

Comment: Would it be safer to create an anonymous type for the results of the zip rather than relying on some character (e.g. a space) to join them, like `var matchingNames = firstNames.Zip(lastNames, (a, b) => new { first = a, last = b }).Where(x => x.first == myFirstName && x.last == myLastName);`?

Comment: A gotcha is that it will only zip up to the least number of elements in an collection. So if collection `A` has 10 elements, and `B` has 20 elements, it will only zip the first 10 of each collection.

Comment: @Cameron Agree, but I had assumed (possibly incorrectly) that it was a one to one matching, otherwise two where's would work

Comment: @AndrewMorton Yes, I am actually more heavily into scala and was thrown off when a tuple wasn't returned for the concatenation. That being said, there is no added safety as you are essentially doing the same thing. Now, if you want the discrete data as the final output, then an anonymous object would be beneficial

Comment: @JustinPihony Yea.. I didn't make the assumption. I just wanted to point it out. I know I've seen a question here on SO, grabbed code, and not looked up how it actually works. Then been aggravated when it didn't quite work out like I had expected.